# Exposing as a WCF an encapsulated ReceiveSendReply activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a NativeActivity that encapsulates a ReceiveSendReply actvity with a simply operation GetData() with string parameters. When I dropped this compiled actvity onto a xamlx hosted in IIS/AppFabric and try to call the receive actvity through WCF, I get an exception that no one is listening at that EndPoint.  If I replace my compiled actvity with messaging actvities in xamlx with same names, service contracts and parameters it works.

I want to be able to encapsulate the Receive and Send activities so that the business analyst does not have to worry about these non-business activities.

So my first question is: Is encapsulating Receive and Send actvities in a Native Actvity suppose to work and get exposed as a WCF endpoint when used within a xamlx?

My second question is if there a sample for this.  Most samples that I found use a home made Service host to establish the end point.  I want to embed this in a xamlx and expose it though IIS/AppFabric.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Kas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should just work, it doesn't matter if you drop the Receive and SendReply on a workflow or use them through code inside a NativeActivity. The ReceiveSendReply is not a activity but a template that does a bit of basic configuration and I am guessing you are missing some of the configuration steps.

As far as samples there is very little difference in self hosting or using IIS/AppFabric. In both cases the WorklfowServiceHost is used and all the same rules apply. The only things is IIS preconfigures some things like the base address for you and makes management easier. But samples should still be valid in almost all cases.